# SQL Splitting dataset into 3 sections 60/20/20 for testing

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that I want to split into 3 groups and the splits to be 60/20/20. I would also like the split to be random. Was wondering what is the best method to do this using SQL (redshift). I tried using percent rank but that doesn't work so open to ideas.

Thanks.

Example data:

| ID | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123214123 | Y |
| 544354342 | N |
| 43241231 | Y |
| 231213123 | Y |
| 123123123 | Y |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is probably just using `random()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when random() < 0.6 then 'group1'
             when random() < 0.5 then 'group2'
             else 'group3'
        end)
from t;
```

This is only approximate in the counts.  You can get more precision using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ntile <= 6 then 'group1'
             when ntile <= 8 then 'group2'
             else 'group3'
        end)
from (select t.*,
             ntile(10) over (order by random()) as tile
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything that is 100% accurate ?

Comment: @Sully . . . The `ntile()` version will produce portions that are exactly 60-20-20 if possible.  And if the number of rows is not exactly a multiple of 5, then they will be off by at most one row.